# Print more lines to Python console

Tags: python, console

I'm currently working on a large dataset that prints about 6500 lines of data. Unfortunately, the Python console only prints the last (+-) 100 lines of data, and I would like to expand the console to show all lines. Is there a possibility to do this, or would it be better to export it to e.g. Excel?

Comment: you should use a file, a simple .txt file or a log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing to a text file:

```py
m = "how to\n"
x = ["write\n","to\n","text\n","file"]
with open("file.txt","w") as file:
    file.write(m)      #str input
    file.writelines(x) #list input
```

Or if your data needs to be formatted like an Excel file, look into the `xlsxwriter` module. It's generally much better practice to write data to files rather than print to console as far as I know.